# SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getObjectSharingInformation in SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint

In the SharePoint JavaScript Object Model, there is SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getObjectSharingInformation, as described in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850859.aspx

Is this method available in the SharePoint REST API? I would like to use it to get the list of people with whom a SharePoint list has been shared with.